# How to integrate Lightbox in a shiny application?

Tags: image, shiny, lightbox

I am building a shiny application that renders large number of images in the form of tiles.  I want to integrate [Lightbox jScript](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) into my application, something similar to the four image set example given. How do i do that.

The data file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Ktx_VPzoQ0U2FHYkpEOWpOVGM).
The styles.css [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Ktx_VPzoQ0UjJsX3p0N003Sm8).

The minimal working codes:

UI:

```
shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "green",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "MYAPP"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                        useShinyjs(),
                        includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
                        includeCSS("www/lightbox.css"),
                        includeCSS("www/lightbox.min.css"),
                        includeScript("www/lightbox.js"),
                        includeScript("www/lightbox.min.js"),
                        sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                            menuItem("PICTURES & IMAGES", tabName = "imag", icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"))
                            )
                        ),
                    dashboardBody(
                        tabItems(
                            tabItem(
                                tabName = "imag", h3("PICTURES & IMAGES"),
                                fluidRow(
                                        uiOutput("picss")
                                        )
                                )
                        ))

))
```

The server code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      output$picss <- renderUI({
        fluidRow(
            column(12, id="columns",
                   lapply(df1$recipe.link, function(i) {
                       box(width=NULL,
                             title = HTML(paste0("<div class='image-wrap'>
                                                <img src='./images/",
                                                 df1$img[df1$recipe.link == i],"'class=fixed-height'",
                                                 df1$img[df1$recipe.link == i],
                                                "'></div>"           
                             ))
                       )}
                   )))
    })

})
```

The global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(base64enc)

df1 <- readRDS("df1.RDS")
filepath <- "www/images/"
dir.create(file.path(filepath), showWarnings = FALSE)
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1[i,"image_path"] == "NULL"){
    next
  }
  testObj <- strsplit(df1[i,"image_path"],",")[[1]][2]
  inconn <- testObj
  outconn <- file(paste0(filepath,"image_id",df1[i,"id"],".jpg"),"wb")
  base64decode(what=inconn, output=outconn)
  close(outconn)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to reproduce the Four image set (in your case three images) this is how I was able to do it.

In the ui.R i have use tagList to include all the necessary components. Note the by [Lightbox instructions](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Point 3 of getting started lightbox.js should be included at the bottom of the body.

Just be sure to put the correct paths back for inlcudeCSS and includeJS since I have changed them.

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyUI(tagList(
            tags$head(
                    useShinyjs(),
                    includeCSS("www/css/styles.css"),
                    includeCSS("www/css/lightbox.css")
            ),
            dashboardPage(skin = "green",
                          dashboardHeader(title = "MYAPP"),
                          dashboardSidebar(

                                  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                              menuItem("PICTURES & IMAGES", tabName = "imag", icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"))
                                  )
                          ),
                          dashboardBody(
                                  tabItems(
                                          tabItem(
                                                  tabName = "imag", h3("PICTURES & IMAGES"),
                                                  fluidRow(
                                                          uiOutput("picss")
                                                  )
                                          )
                                  ))


    ),
    includeScript("www/js/lightbox.js")
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            output$picss <- renderUI({
                    fluidRow(
                            column(12, id="columns",
                                   lapply(df1$recipe.link, function(i) {
                                           box(width=NULL,
                                               title = HTML(paste0('<div class="image-wrap"><a href="images/',
                                                                   df1[df1$recipe.link == i, 6],
                                                                   '" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img border="0" alt="" class="fixed-height" src="images/'
                                                                   ,df1[df1$recipe.link == i, 6],'"></a></div>'))

                                           )}
                                   )

                                   ))
            })

    })
```

global.R is unchanged.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Beakovic Thank a tonne for the help...this is really fabulous....i implemented this in my production environment and it works perfect.  I was struggling with this for the last two days...using <a href =  and data-lightbox without any success...sometime the href worked properly but the image was not rendering...another mistake was, I was not using tagList..this is super helpful.  Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Glad it helped! "as curious to see since I am considering to use it ine one small app.

Comment: Yes, it did!  My dataset has 1000's of pics and i am using filters to subset by markets and other parameters....when I passed on the reactive data frame, everything fell in place.  I kind of tweaked the `data-title="My caption">` to provide relevant information in multiple lines below the picture fed from the reactive df.  While I understand the math and stat part of R, for me creating a web interface is a challenge.  I am really thankful for this entire community helping me to learn and feel empowered.

Comment: Hi @ValterBeaković ,  I have successfully used your solution to implement the lightbox function, but the thumbnails were displayed in 1 x N (one image per row), and I want to display these thumbnails in M x N (M images per row). I have no idea how to modify your solution to handle this situation. Could you please give me some suggestions? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @just_rookie I can take a look but my private and business situation doesn't leave me much time to dedicate to Stackoverflow.com. This means that it will not be that quick...